# apache compression Deflate .js and .css files not compressed?

Tags: apache, gzip, yslow, deflate

In Apache Im enabling output compression by adding the following to my .htaccess file:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

So I'm serving all content with Content-Encoding: gzip but when I test my webpage with Yslow I receive:

```
Grade D on Compress components with gzip

There are 3 plain text components that should be sent compressed

* http://mysite.com/javascript/youTubeEmbed/youTubeEmbed-jquery-1.0.css
* http://mysite.com/javascript/jquery.swfobject.1-1-1.min.js
* http://mysite.com/javascript/youTubeEmbed/youTubeEmbed-jquery-1.0.js
```

Where's the problem?Shouldn't they get compressed automatically??

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Did you remember to clear your cache before reloading the page and running Yslow?

I had the exact same problem and fixed it like that.  This is my code:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Somehow, I solved my problem by adding: stylesheet and script also, for google chrome (didn't check on other browsers) somehow Apache didn't recognized text/css nor any javascript variations but script in google chrome.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I resolved the exact same problem just adding this line to the .htaccess file:
**AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript**

Maybe the server is not getting javascript as **application/javascript** but **text/javascript**. Hope it helps.

Comment: That did it for me too! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to remove the Reverse-Proxy-Server (nginx) - of course, you can also configure compression using the nginx.conf file (may be located in /etc/nginx or use an own .conf file located in /etc/nginx/conf.d directory) - but nginx caused some other problems.
Having removed nginx from a Server using Plesk have a look at these hints:
http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=260563
To cut a long story short: Take care wether the files are really served by your Apache or they are handled by something like nginx.
B.t.w. a quick testing tool:
http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php