# compression not working in apache

Tags: apache

I have this setup in my httpd.conf file:

```
<files *.js>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

but for some reason, nothing is being compressed. I've cleared the cache in my browser and restarted my apache server. Why am I not get file compression?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405347/apache-compression-deflate-js-and-css-files-not-compressed

Comment: i tried clearing the cache, I also use the AddOutputFilterByType. Neither works. I'd rather add compression my file extension though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I had to add this line of code before the setoutputfilter:

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```